# horizontal recyclerview inside vertical recycerview adapter

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

`enter code here` i am using recyclerview  but i need to implement one more
    recyclerview inside the adapter layout of the recyclerview. Can
    anyone tell me how can i set the json data   to the recyclerview
    which is inside the cardview of verticsal recycler. Dont tell me
    about how to set the horizontal recyclerview i know it very well.
    the problem with me is that i am confused that how to set data to
    recyclerview which is inside cardview of vertical recyclerview

Comment: Could you please add the code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `List>` to the vertical RecyclerView's adapter and then in the `onBindViewHolder`, pass the inner list at some index `i` to the constructor of horizontal RecyclerView's adapter.

Answer (score 0):

For the outer vertical RecyclerView, use this extended class:

```
public class BetterRecyclerView extends RecyclerView{
  private static final int INVALID_POINTER = -1;
  private int mScrollPointerId = INVALID_POINTER;
  private int mInitialTouchX, mInitialTouchY;
  private int mTouchSlop;
  public BetterRecyclerView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
  }

  public BetterRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
  }

  public BetterRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    final ViewConfiguration vc = ViewConfiguration.get(getContext());
    mTouchSlop = vc.getScaledTouchSlop();
  }

  @Override
  public void setScrollingTouchSlop(int slopConstant) {
    super.setScrollingTouchSlop(slopConstant);
    final ViewConfiguration vc = ViewConfiguration.get(getContext());
    switch (slopConstant) {
      case TOUCH_SLOP_DEFAULT:
        mTouchSlop = vc.getScaledTouchSlop();
        break;
      case TOUCH_SLOP_PAGING:
        mTouchSlop = ViewConfigurationCompat.getScaledPagingTouchSlop(vc);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    final int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(e);
    final int actionIndex = MotionEventCompat.getActionIndex(e);

    switch (action) {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        mScrollPointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(e, 0);
        mInitialTouchX = (int) (e.getX() + 0.5f);
        mInitialTouchY = (int) (e.getY() + 0.5f);
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(e);

      case MotionEventCompat.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
        mScrollPointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(e, actionIndex);
        mInitialTouchX = (int) (MotionEventCompat.getX(e, actionIndex) + 0.5f);
        mInitialTouchY = (int) (MotionEventCompat.getY(e, actionIndex) + 0.5f);
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(e);

      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
        final int index = MotionEventCompat.findPointerIndex(e, mScrollPointerId);
        if (index < 0) {
          return false;
        }

        final int x = (int) (MotionEventCompat.getX(e, index) + 0.5f);
        final int y = (int) (MotionEventCompat.getY(e, index) + 0.5f);
        if (getScrollState() != SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
          final int dx = x - mInitialTouchX;
          final int dy = y - mInitialTouchY;
          final boolean canScrollHorizontally = getLayoutManager().canScrollHorizontally();
          final boolean canScrollVertically = getLayoutManager().canScrollVertically();
          boolean startScroll = false;
          if (canScrollHorizontally && Math.abs(dx) > mTouchSlop && (Math.abs(dx) >= Math.abs(dy) || canScrollVertically)) {
            startScroll = true;
          }
          if (canScrollVertically && Math.abs(dy) > mTouchSlop && (Math.abs(dy) >= Math.abs(dx) || canScrollHorizontally)) {
            startScroll = true;
          }
          return startScroll && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(e);
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(e);
      }

      default:
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(e);
    }
  }
}
```

For the inner horizontal RecyclerView, use this extended class:

```
public class FeedRootRecyclerView extends BetterRecyclerView{  
  public FeedRootRecyclerView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
  }

  public FeedRootRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
  }

  public FeedRootRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  }

  @Override
  public void requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {
    /* do nothing */
  }
}
```

You can find proper explanation as to what these classes do over here : http://nerds.headout.com/fix-horizontal-scrolling-in-your-android-app/

Comment: Please don't add [the same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41940784/4687348) to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/347985)